# Can't read property 'weather' of undefined javascript in weather app

Tags: javascript, json

Thanks for everything guys, i had it right the first time but because of something else i kept getting confused and was trying to fix something that wasn't broken lol.

Comment: sorry, stated that question badly. I'm trying to use the var data in a function that way i can do

Comment: As I explained in my answer, you can refer to data, not to this.data, but it's a bad idea

Answer (score 1):

First one works because your are trying to access to global data object, which is initialized. And in the constructor you pass already got description

```
var data = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
var weatherData = new Weather(cityName, data.weather[0].description.toUpperCase());`

function Weather(cityName, description) {
    this.cityName = cityName
    this.description = description;
    this._temperature = '';
}
```

In the second case you are tring to access `this.data.weahter`, but you don't have any `this.data` in your object

```
var data = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
var weatherData = new Weather(cityName, data);

function Weather(cityName, datacity) {
    this.cityName = cityName
    this.data.weather[0].description.toUpperCase() = description;
      // ^ here your don't have data object, also neithier the weather for accessing by index

    this._temperature = '';
}
```

I think you only mistyped the property names and you need

```
var data = JSON.parse(http.responseText);
var weatherData = new Weather(cityName, data);

function Weather(cityName, datacity) {
    this.cityName = cityName
    this.description = datacity.weather[0].description.toUpperCase();
    this._temperature = '';
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The first one is accessing a variable that you've defined, called `data`. The second one is trying to use `this.data` which was never defined.

It's hard to tell why you think it should work.

It will work if you remove `this.` from `this.data`, but that doesn't really make sense, since you usually avoid accessing a global variable from inside an object